Understanding the proof of Goldston–Pintz–Yíldírím's theorem
I hope this question fits the mission of this site.
In "Primes in Tuples I" theorem 2 says,
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}{\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log p_n}}=0.$$
After a sieving progress you get $$h>\left(r-\frac{2k}{k+2\ell+1}\frac{2\ell+1}{\ell+1}\left(\frac{\vartheta}{2}-\varepsilon\right)\right)\log N.$$ Letting $\ell=\left[\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2}\right]$ gives a simpler inequality and theorem 2 is solved with $r=1$, $\vartheta=1/2$.
How is it solved? How did we end up with such a conclusion with that inequality? Also this error term $$E_r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf{\frac{p_{n+r}-p_n}{\log p_n}} \text{?}$$

probably  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n2-p10-p.pdf

apparently formula (3.9)  except the $r$ here should be $\nu$

I recommend that you study the following blog entry by Terry Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/polymath8b-bounded-intervals-with-many-primes-after-maynard/ It describes the proof of Maynard's much stronger theorem (sometimes called the Maynard-Tao theorem), which is based on an improved version of the Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim sieve. The point is that the subject has cleaned up considerably, and Terry Tao explains things wonderfully.

In equation (3.10)
$$ h> \left( v- 2\vartheta + 4\epsilon + O \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right) \right) \log N$$  we substitute $v=1, \vartheta =1/2$ and so can take $$ h> \left( 4\epsilon + O \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right) \right) \log N.$$
Now the conclusion we can draw is that there are at least $v+1=2$ primes in some interval $(n,n+h]$ for $N< n \leq 2N$.  For $p_m$ the first prime in that interval and $p_{m+1}$ another prime in that interval, we have $p_{m+1}-p_m<h$ and $ p_m > n> N$ so $\log p_m > \log N$ and thus $$ \frac{p_{m+1}-p_m}{\log p_m} < \frac{h}{\log N} .$$ Taking $h$ close to the lower bound we get
$$ \frac{p_{m+1}-p_m}{\log p_m} < 4 \epsilon + O \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right) .$$
Now we can let $\epsilon$ go to $0$ and $O \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right)$ goes to $0$ so the lim inf of the expression on the left goes to $0$.

CW.....The likely page in Goldston, Pintz, Yildirim, Annals(2009)


The thing is i dont understand how it is solving the problem. I know it sounds like not understanding 2+2=4 in well known arithmetic laws but, how is the sieving that range gives us that ratio? (Where did $1/logp_n$ come from?)

@ArdaYonet Honestly from the way you phrased the question it seems it would take a lot more than a MathOverflow answer to explain to you how the argument works overall. Is there someone you can talk to about this offline?

It's more up to laziness but yes I'm really new to sieve theory. Unfortunately there is noone to talk. Is there any suggestion for reading?

I highly recommend this survey written by Soundararajan (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605696) on the work of GPY (written before the Maynard-Tao developments, but explains the GPY strategy very clearly).
